# Cassandra query got timeout when filter with partition key

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0

I am new with Cassandra db, now I am working on it and got a problem with query select.

This is my Cassandra table:

```
CREATE TABLE abc (
module text,
cid uuid,
date timestamp,
oid int,
PRIMARY KEY (module, cid)
)
```

On this table I need to create a query:

```
select * from abc where module=aaa
```

This query return a timeout said:

```
<SELECT * FROM canibis.cacherefresh WHERE module = Listing LIMIT 5000>, total time 5031 msec, timeout 5000 msec/cross-node
```

Question is: I filter by partition key but the log says **cross-node**, does anyone known why?

Answer (score 0):

> This query return a timeout said:

<SELECT * FROM canibis.cacherefresh WHERE module = Listing LIMIT 5000>, total time 5031 msec

This is not a timeout, this message is logged when some operation is deemed slow as per expectation. This message is just to inform that operation slow was observed.

> Question is: I filter by partition key but the log says cross-node, does anyone known why?

If your query require to go to other node for completion, then it becomes cross node operation. So above message is just informing you that your operation was slow and it was internode operation thats why it says timeout 5000 msec/cross-node.

If there are only few such messages then it could be due to GC pauses.

Comment: @ Manish Can you explain to me why that's query need to go cross-node? as I understand, each partition will be stored on a node (except replicas) so for the query, I assume that should look in one node is enough.

Comment: It could be that if you are reading with Consistency more than one. Also it could be due to your query landing on a particular node where data is not present.